# Jrebel for spring batch application in unix

Tags: unix, spring-batch, jrebel

Since our spring batch process takes lots of time, we want to deploy the Java changes without restarting our unix script.
This unix script basically has the commands to run our main Java class.
I want to enable functionality of jrebel in our application.
Went through a number of documents, but didn't find any proper one.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your IDE, you can follow whole configuration [here](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ide/index.html#jrebel-in-your-ide)

You don't add JRebel javaagent to application server but you need to add JRebel `-agentpath` argument to the JVM command:

```
Windows 64-bit JDK  java -agentpath:C:\JRebel\lib\jrebel64.dll com.example.Main
Windows 32-bit JDK  java -agentpath:C:\JRebel\lib\jrebel32.dll com.example.Main
Mac OS X 64-bit JDK java -agentpath:/home/user/jrebel/lib/libjrebel64.dylib com.example.Main
Mac OS X 32-bit JDK java -agentpath:/home/user/jrebel/lib/libjrebel32.dylib com.example.Main
Linux 64-bit JDK    java -agentpath:/home/user/jrebel/lib/libjrebel64.so com.example.Main
Linux 32-bit JDK    java -agentpath:/home/user/jrebel/lib/libjrebel32.so com.example.Main
```